# ListObjects operation's limit on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I am going through the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjects) of `ListObjects` function in AWS' `go` SDK.

(the same holds more or less for the [actual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) API endpoint)

So the docs write:

> Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket.

What does this mean? If my bucket has 200.000 objects this API call will not work?

[This](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/example/service/s3/listObjects/listObjects.go) example uses `ListObjectsPages` (which calls `ListObjects` under the hood) and claims to list **all** objects.

What is the actual case here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am going through the documentation of ListObjects function in AWS' go SDK.

Use ListObjectsV2.  It behaves more or less the same, but it's an updated version of ListObjects.  It's not super common for AWS to update APIs, and when they do, it's usually for a good reason.  They're great about backwards compatibility which is why `ListObjects` still exists.

> This example uses ListObjectsPages (which calls ListObjects under the hood) and claims to list all objects.

`ListObjectsPages` is  a paginated equivalent of `ListObjects`, and ditto for the `V2` versions which I'll describe below.

Many AWS API responses are paginated.  AWS uses Cursor Pagination; this means [request responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#ListObjectsV2Output) include a cursor - `ContinuationToken` in the case of ListObjectsV2 . If more objects exist (`IsTruncated` in the response), a subsequent [ListObjectsV2 request content can provide the ContinuationToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#ListObjectsV2Input) to continue the listing where the first response left off.

`ListObjectsV2Pages` handles the iterative `ListObjectsV2` requests for you so you don't have to handle the logic of `ContinuationToken` and `IsTruncated`.  Instead, you provide a function that will be invoked for each "page" in the response.

So it's accurate to say `ListObjectsV2Pages` will list "all" the objects, but it's because it makes *multiple* `ListObjectsV2` calls in the backend that it will list more than one page of responses.

Thus, `...Pages` functions can be considered convenience functions.  You should always use them when appropriate - they take away the pain of pagination, and pagination is critical to make potentially high volume api responses operable.  In AWS, if pagination is supported, assume you need it - in typical cases, the first page of results is not guaranteed to contain *any* results, even if subsequent pages do.

Answer (score 1):

[The AWS Go SDK V2](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/) gives us paginator types to help us manage S3's per-query item limits. `ListObjectsV2Pages` is gone.  In its place we get [ListObjectsV2Paginator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#NewListObjectsV2Paginator), which deals with the pagination details that @Daniel_Farrell mentioned.

The constructor accepts the same params as the list objects query (`type ListObjectsV2Input`).  The paginator exposes 2 methods: `HasMorePages: bool` and `NextPage: (*ListObjectsV2Output, error)`.

```golang
var items []Item

for p.HasMorePages() {
  batch, err := p.NextPage(ctx)
  // etc...
  item = append(items, newItems...)
}
```